# Sampling Constraint Violation in GridDB

Tags: griddb

So I have created a container, `conInfo` in GridDB comprising of used car sales where the schema of the container looks as follows:

```js
const conInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "usedcaranalysis",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["Sales_ID", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["year", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["selling_price", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["km_driven", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["Region", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["State or Province", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["City", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["fuel", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seller_type", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["transmission", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["owner", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["mileage", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["engine", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["max_power", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["torque", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seats", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["sold", griddb.Type.STRING]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});
```

I wrote a TQL query to retrieve a random sample of 5% of the `selling_price` of the used cars, where the output should not exceed 100 cars:

```sql
SELECT *

FROM conInfo TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(5)

LIMIT(100);
```

But I received the following error:

```
[Server]: 70004

[Description] (Sampling interval constraint violation)

[Format] Error description below

Interval value is 0 or a negative value
```

However, the `selling_price` of the cars does not have either zero or negative values. I am unable to understand and figure out the root cause of sampling constraint violations. Any suggestions?